# -bash: rsvg: command not found

Tags: homebrew, imagemagick, osx-yosemite

I installed ImageMagick

```
brew install imagemagick --with-librsvg
```

And installation went fine, however when I try to run imagemagick in console I see:

```
-bash: imagemagick: command not found
```

How can add stuff installed with HomeBrew to bash path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation will make available various libraries and [Command-line Tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php). There isn't one named imagemagick. It's a software suite, and it's libraries ofttimes used by tools.

If you've installed an X server ImageMagick's X GUI can be launched with the command `display` without any arguments. (See the [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) website for installing X).

Click on the splash screen image and a menu will pop up.

You might prefer the command-line interfaces to various tools. Before looking at the [librsvg](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/download/) then [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php) websites for an answer I had never used the GUI functionality (I'm a long time UNIX and Linux user).

Comment: Well, librsvg should install rsvg command tool, isn't it? It's not found either.

Comment: librsvg does not install an executable named `rsvg`. There is an `rsvg-convert` included in the librsvg source, for which you might now have a man page if librsvg is actually installed.